# Compilation Error: [No relevant source lines]

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I'm getting this error when trying to view a page in my localhost. Web site worked before. The code files are not pre-compiled. I've cleaned asp.net temporary folders and gave full control permission to IIS_IUSRS account for wwwroot and Temporary ASP.NET Files folder but no change.

I also get Access Denied error while try to execute

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** BC2000: compiler initialization failed unexpectedly: 0x80070005

**Source Error:** [No relevant source lines]

**Source File:** vbc : Fatal    **Line:** 0

**Detailed Compiler Output:**

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\vbc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edc6d145\6ccb6f45\assembly\dl3\5a446507\0042bc76_16cec701\Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edc6d145\6ccb6f45\App_SubCode_vb.8xqaf3z2.dll" /D:DEBUG=1 /debug+ /define:_MYTYPE=\"Web\" /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Specialized,System.Configuration,System.Text,System.Text.RegularExpressions,System.Web,System.Web.Caching,System.Web.SessionState,System.Web.Security,System.Web.Profile,System.Web.UI,System.Web.UI.WebControls,System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts,System.Web.UI.HtmlControls,System.Web.Configuration,System.Data,System.Data.OleDb,System.Globalization /warnaserror- /optionInfer+  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edc6d145\6ccb6f45\App_SubCode_vb.8xqaf3z2.0.vb" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edc6d145\6ccb6f45\App_SubCode_vb.8xqaf3z2.1.vb"

Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 9.0.30729.715
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

vbc : Fatal error BC2000 : compiler initialization failed unexpectedly: 0x80070005
```

Comment: What OS are you on? Does it work with the development ASP.NET server?

Comment: Win7. Yes its working on development server.

Comment: What happens if you remove the new website?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, try setting "**Enable 32-bit Applications**" to True for your website application pool if you are running on x64 machine.

If first option doesn't help, Grant Full Accesses for **NETWORK SERVICE** and **IIS_IUSRS** group on C:\Windows\Temp\ and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Comment: Yes, Thank you. "Enable 32-bit Applications" fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after repairing / upgrading my VS 2013 Express

I first tried adding "IIS_IUSRS" and "NETWORK SERVICE" with Modify to the following:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\local\path\to\NET_App
C:\Windows\Temp
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Those did not work. But then I removed the optimizeCompilations="true" from the compilation tag under system.web and everything worked great.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" batch="false" optimizeCompilations="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i add `.ascx` and use it in `.aspx`, but `src` path was wrong, add:

```
tagPrefix="uc" src="~/Signup**d**/UserControls/CreditCheck.ascx" tagName="CreditCheck"
```

Comment: Are you saying this solution worked?  It isn't immediately clear from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to Grant Full Accesses for NETWORK SERVICE user and Modify Rights for the IIS_IUSERS to your ASP.NET root application folder.

The issue was caused by web.config transformation. It needs to create a temp file in the root application folder.

Answer (score 0):

The line zero behaviour is generally caused by compiling with optimizations turned on (eg inlining). Try unchecking "Optimize code" under your project's Properties - Build tab. Then Source Error will show the offending code with line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.

My Symptom: it was working find on local but was failing on dev/stage.
Reason I found: There was an appvariable used in aspx.cs (as following) which was missing in web.config

public static String myKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"].ToString();

Reason it took long for me to figure out issue was, i was not expecting this type of error message on line 0 (may be because my developer defined this variable as static so it was throwing line 0 error)

Answer (score 0):

We converted our webapps to 64 bit quite some time ago and I still see this error jumping between old solutions. However, suddenly none of the standard good answers found on this thread worked.

Here is what ended up fixing my case.  In Visual Studio 2019 in the project properties, on the application tab, where you choose the framework, there is an option to "Install other frameworks..." It will link you to here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk . I downloaded and reinstalled, by choosing the repair option, the .Net Framework 4.8.1 Developer Pack and all is well now.

The only possible explanation why mine went bad is a Windows Update, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I was converting an aspx web form to be based on a master page.  Upon testing, the error for no relevant source lines appeared.  The `<!DOCTYPE html>` line was left in and upon removing it, the issue was resolved.