# No Conceptual Schema error using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, entity-framework-5

I'm creating a website with Entity Framework, and have had quite a bit of fun due to changing from VS2010 to VS2012 (which deals with DBContexts instead of ObjectContexts).  I had to recreate the Entity Model a couple of times, and I think I've got it all sorted out, but I'm now getting the following error on the staging machine:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: No Conceptual Schema node to embed as a resource

Source Error: 

[No relevant source lines]
```

Everything is working on the local machine.  The data model is pointing to the same sql server database on the network for both local and staging (for now, the next trick is to get the staging to point to the live data, but that's a problem for a different SO question :).

I have found little info on the 'No conceptual schema ...' error message, but I have checked that 'Enable 32-Bit Applications' is set to true as advised here:  [Compilation Error: [No relevant source lines]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491943/compilation-error-no-relevant-source-lines)

Does anyone know how to deal with this error?  I'm lost.

Comment: Consider using web application instead of website - I think websites are treated as legacy. Anyway here is a comparison chart http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx. Anyways for me it seems like there is a link to the CSDL (or edmx) file in your website project but the file is not actually there...

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for looking in.  I have got the CSDL file in the project, both on the dev and staging machines.  I think in this instance the problem is starting the project in VS2010 and then using VS2012.  I've now dropped the target back to 4.0, changed the Model from DbContext back to ObjectContext and it seems to be working again.  (I'm doing web apps instead of sites for new projects, but I've got some legacy to deal with :) I'm just leaving the question up for a week or so to see if others who know more than me - such as yourself - can shed some light on the issue.